# Convergence of a Series involving Gamma Function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

I was studying the Gamma Functions, and while looking for different series involving Gamma functions, I saw the following one:

> For all $c \in [0,\infty)$ and $\epsilon \in (0,\infty)$, the series:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{c^{n}}{\Gamma(n\epsilon)}$$
>   converges.

Well, as an immediate observation, we can trivially ignore the case $c =0$, and start looking for the case $c \in (0,\infty)$. What I have tried so far, is the conventional Ratio test and **Rabe's test**. Now, I think there is some kind of obvious trick which I may not know lying here.

So, please let me know if you have any kind of way out.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Oh yes!! I forgot to mention, I have considered the case of $n \epsilon \lt 1$ & $|c| \lt 1$, which are easy (as it seems to me) by Dirichlet's Test. But, I am clueless about the general scenario.

Comment: :| Have you not looked at my answer yet?

Comment: oops... Sorry!! I just saw it now. Very sorry. Thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Stirling approximation (limit comparison test)  and the root test.  It should come through rather obviously.

Also use $\Gamma(n\epsilon)=\frac{\Gamma(1+n\epsilon)}{n\epsilon}$.

It then converges for $c\in(-\infty,0)$ by absolute convergence.

---

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n\epsilon)}{\frac1\epsilon\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}n}\left(\frac{n\epsilon}e\right)^n}=1$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{c^n}{\frac1\epsilon\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}n}\left(\frac{n\epsilon}e\right)^n}\right|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|c|\cdot e\cdot\epsilon\cdot\sqrt[n]n}{\sqrt[n]{2\pi}n\epsilon}=0$$

Thus, it converges for all $c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art, I know Stirling's approximation. Please let me know how you are writing the first limit. I mean how you are replacing the factorial, appearing in Stirling's formula ??

Comment: @user92360 I replaced the factorial with the Gamma function (they are equivalent), using the following: $$\Gamma(1+n)=n!,\qquad\Gamma(n)=\frac{\Gamma(1+n)}n$$

Comment: But, here "$n\epsilon$" may NOT be an integer.Right ?? So, you can't write $\Gamma (1+n) = n!$ . Isn't it ??

Comment: Yuup got it. Had to check the section on Stirling's Formula of the Wikipedia page on Gamma Function. Thanks a ton... (Y)

Comment: Of course, but Stirling's approximation works for the gamma function at non-integer values as well.